# How to create a named instance of SQL Express 2016 programmatically?

Tags: sql-server-express, sql-server-2016

I need to create a named instance of SQL Express 2016 programmatically.

The default instance is ".\SQLExpress" which is alright. Apart from this, I need an additional instance say "MyInstance" to be created. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried scripting the installation then calling the script from whatever automation/app you want to use? Check out details on command line setup for SQL Server here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx. You can also use [config files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239405.aspx) which may be more or less friendly for your automation.

Outside of that, there's not really a programmatic installation of SQL Server. Remember, you're running the setup executable to install. There is no service that you make API calls to get things done unless you're using Azure SQL DB or SQL Server in Azure VMs. Those have REST APIs you can use to provision new DBs/instances.

Comment: Command line did the trick. Sharing the command line here in case someone needs it as well in future. setup.exe /ACTION=Install /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS /UpdateEnabled=False /FEATURES=SQL,Tools /SQLCOLLATION=SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS /QS